# Override package definition in ConTeXt presentation

Tags: context, presentations

I am using ConTeXt for my presentation. More specifically, I used the following code:

```
\usemodule[pre-split]

\starttext
    \TitlePage{Famous Quotes}

    \Topic{\sc Tufte} 
    \input tufte

    \Topic{\sc Knuth}
    \input knuth\page
    \Subject{By the way...}
    \input knuth

    \Topic{\sc Reich}
    \input reich
\stoptext
```

All is working as expected except the colors. In the source code (http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/sources/s-pre-14.pdf) I found at line 7:

```
\definecolor [One] [r=.6,g=.4,b=.4]
\definecolor [Two] [r=.4,g=.6,b=.6]
```

How can I override those definitions?
I would like the reddish color to be white.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Colors aren’t fixed and you can always redefine them with the `\definecolor` command.

```
\starttext

\definecolor [Red] [r=1]

\color[Red]{Is this text red?}

\definecolor [Red] [g=1]

\color[Red]{Is this text red?}

\definecolor [Red] [magenta]

\color[Red]{Is this text red?}

\stoptext
```

[image]

To change the colors which are set in a module you have to change the values after the module was loaded.

```
\usemodule[pre-split]

\definecolor [One] [white]
\definecolor [Two] [red]

\starttext
...
\stoptext
```

Comment: Did you test the code? It works with `\color` but not for the presentation.

Comment: Actually the text on the side bar was affected but not the background.

Comment: @Blincer The background uses the colors `ColorOne` (for the left part) and  `ColorTwo` (for the right part) which have to be changed and not the colors `One` and `Two` mentioned in your post.

Comment: You are right, sorry :) `\definecolor [ColorOne] [r=1,g=1,b=1]` and
`\definecolor [ColorTwo] [r=.4,g=.6,b=.6]` are perfect.

Comment: However, how did you find the name `ColorOne` what I see in the code is `backgroundcolor=One`. I may mistake @Wolfgang Schuster.

Comment: @Blincer You’re looking at the wrong file. The style you use is in your example in the file `s-present-split.mkiv` which uses the two colors mentioned above.